# Reading single element innertext from large xml file

Tags: c#, xml, innertext

I have a large single node .xml file that I have saved as a string. I want to parse the .xml file for a specific element read and output the innertext. EG: I want to read the FrameNo element and output BINGO to a messagebox. The desired element will only appear once in the .xml document. I prefer using XmlDocument.

I have tried numerous C# .xml examples but am unable to get a output.

xml text is

```
    <Aircraft z:Id="i1" xmlns="http://xxx.yyyyycontract.gov/2018/03/Boeing.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.Airframe" 
    xmlns:i="http://www.xxxxxxx.com/2019/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:z="http://xxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.com/2005/01/Serialization/"><Timestamp i:nil="true"/> 
    <Uuid>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Uuid><Comments i:nil="true"/><Facility>..........
```

and so on to the end of the .xml

```
    <FrameNo>BINGO</FrameNo><WDate i:nil="true"/></Aircraft>
```

this is the code section I want to have the code execute in.

```
    private void buttonLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

Comment: `XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();` then use `doc.Load(filePath);` to load your XML file, and `string text = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("FrameNo").InnerText`

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is self-explanatory

```cs
using System.Xml.Linq;

XElement root = XElement.Load(textXML);
XElement myElement = root.Element("FrameNo");
if (myElement != null)
    myData = myElement.InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the default namespace.  See my xml linq solution below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            XElement frameNo = doc.Descendants(ns + "FrameNo").FirstOrDefault();

            string frame = (string)frameNo;
            string[] serialNumbers = doc.Descendants(ns + "SerialNumber").Select(x => (string)x).ToArray(); 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it works 100% I have hit an unexpected issue where some elements are configured like this

        <SerialNumber i:nil="true"/>

and I want the value that is in this element

        <SerialNumber>197-15472-145-1990413</SerialNumber>

I have tried everything I can think of to edit or change the value in the "xxxxxx" to include or exclude either the space or a trailing > with no luck. I know its the space in the first example that is causing the issue. Is there anyway to filter or check for trailing characters in or after the "xxxxxxx" so that I only get the <SerialNumber> inner text

Comment: string[] serialNumbers = doc.Descendants(ns + "SerialNumber").Select(x => (string)x).ToArray();

Comment: Again that worked perfectly. I now have the program functioning as i desired. I have added a special thanks to you in the code comments. // a special thank you to jdweng at stackoverflow.com for providing essential coding assistance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to jdweng I wanted to share the final code for others to use. This will function in a method like below

```
    private void buttonMaint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlinputstr); // input string from memory or input file
    XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
                string[] Frame = doc.Descendants(ns + "FrameNo").Select(x => (string)x).ToArray(); // selects element to read + trailing character of >
    string frame = string.Join("", Frame); //converts from array to string
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(frame)) // check for empty result
    {
    txtFrame.Text = "not found"; //outputs to textbox
    }
    else
    {
    txtFrame.Text = (frame); //outputs to textbox
    }
    }
```

Comments are there for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Another weird snag has shown up. Some of the elements are named like this.

```
    <a:SupplierServDoc>
```

the innertext contents of this element is a base64 packet. There is no problem processing the base64 packet.

The code from the above answers does output the base64 correctly but cannot handle the : in the element name. It throws a 3A hex character error.

I have this code that outputs the inntertext but not as a base64 packet. I have also looked into prefix to handle the : but with worse results. I am outputting the base 64 innertext as a .txt file when finished.

```
    XNamespace ad = http://www.mmmmmmmmmm.com";
    XName k = ad + "SupplierServDoc";
    string[] WING = doc.Descendants(k).Select(x => (string)x).ToArray();
    string wing = string.Join("", WING);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(syncd))
    {
    MessageBox.Show("a:SupplierServDoc Base 64 code not found");
    }
    else
    {           
    MessageBox.Show("Test " + wing);
    }
```